# Health endpoint down after reloading datasouce

Tags: spring-boot, singleton, datasource, hikaricp, health-check

I am reloading the datasource as following:

`

```
public Boolean reloadDataSource() {
HikariDataSource dataSource = (HikariDataSource) applicationContext.getBean( name: "datasource”);
log.info("Reloading the Connection poot.");
if (!datasource. isCLosed()) /
datasource. close ();
dataSource = new HikariDataSource(DBConfig.getConfig());
this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate (dataSource);
log. info"Reloaded the Connection pool.");
return true;
```

`

It shutdowns current Hikaripool-1 and starts next Hikaripool-2 but in the /health endpoint shows still shows DOWN with the previous closed pool

```
{
    "status": "DOWN",
    "components": {
        "db": {
            "status": "DOWN",
            "details": {
                "error": "org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed."
            }
        },
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "ping": {
            "status": "UP"
        }
    }
}
```